# Finding a cycle in a directed graph using BFS or DFS

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I tried looking around the Internet but I'm a little stuck at the moment with regards to modifying the BFS or DFS algorithm in order to be able to find a cycle in a directed graph. If the graph were not directed, the DFS algorithm would solve this using back edges, but this method fails when looking at directed graphs.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can maintain a set of visited nodes. If you come to a node that is already in the list, you have found a cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DFS algorithm [classifies graph edges into three categories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Output_of_a_depth-first_search) <sup>*</sup>:

- Forward edges
- Cross edges
- Back edges

If your graph has a back edge, it has a cycle. When you run a DFS algorithm and see a backedge, examine the portion of the path from the vertex to which the back edge leads to the current node will give you a set of nodes from the cycle to which the back edge belongs.

<sup>*</sup> Sometimes, tree edges are treated as a separate category from forward edges, which is insignificant for the purposes of this discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Am I correct in saying that the algorithm will run in O(|V|+|E|) time? I'm asking this because I'm supposed to find an algorithm to detect cycles in directed graphs and then undirected graphs, and the professor said that points will be taken off for algorithms that have equal complexities. (I used DFS with back edges to solve the undirected graph part).

Comment: @user3392518 In undirected graph the complexity will be `O(|V|)`, because at most `V-1` edges can be tree edges, and there are no cross edges (they become back edges).

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of vertices currently in recursion stack of function for DFS traversal. If you reach a vertex that is already in the recursion stack, then there is a cycle in the tree.

Create an array recStack[] and add every vertex visited in it. if you encounter a vertex that is already visited, there exists a cycle and you can print it by passing that vertex again to a modified DFS function for printing

```
bool isGraphCyclic(int v, bool visited[], bool *recStack)
{
    if(visited[v] == false)
    {
        // Mark the current node as visited and part of recursion stack
        visited[v] = true;
        recStack[v] = true;

        // Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex
        list<int>::iterator i;
        for(i = adj[v].begin(); i != adj[v].end(); ++i)
        {
            if ( !visited[*i] && isGraphCyclic(*i, visited, recStack) )
                return true;
            else if (recStack[*i])
                return true;
        }

    }
    recStack[v] = false;  // remove the vertex from recursion stack
    return false;
}
```

Comment: why do we need to keep recStack, can't we just use visited array to check for the cycle. Can you give an example ?

Comment: For directed graph just finding a visited node doesn't ensure the existence of the cycle.
{ 1->3->4
  1->5->4 } this graph doesn't contain cycle which cannot be checked just by checking visited array.

Comment: what will this statement do :
 if ( !visited[*i] && isGraphCyclic(*i, visited, recStack) )